# spring.cache.type=redis in application.properties throws exception on startup

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis

I have added spring.cache.type=redis in properties file but it fails to start up the spring boot applicaiton.

I have tried to remove that, in that case everything works without any isssue.

But if I put cache type as redis, it throws the exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No cache manager could be auto-configured, check your configuration (caching type is 'REDIS')
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:215)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration$CacheManagerValidator.afterPropertiesSet(CacheAutoConfiguration.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you actually added Redis support to the project?

Comment: yes, thats why when I remove the entry cache works fine.